# Is it possible to extract part of a value during xslt transform

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Given geography coordinates as an attribute value of an element:

```
<myelement address="POINT (XX.XXX, -YY.YYY)" />
```

During a transform, is there an easy way to extract the value of latitude or longitude? Or would that be the job for extension methods?

Comment: Could you show an actual **XML code** example of the input? It looks like you could simply use the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions - but at this point I am only guessing.

Comment: i updated the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="myelement">
    <coordinates>
        <lat>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@address, 'POINT ('), ', ')"/>
        </lat>
        <lon>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(@address, ', '), ')')"/>
        </lon>
    </coordinates>
</xsl:template>
```

returns:

```
<coordinates>
  <lat>XX.XXX</lat>
  <lon>-YY.YYY</lon>
</coordinates>
```